# Jquery popup access does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, popupwindow

The HTML of the popup is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jq/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<html>
    <body>
        <div id="revi_sec_report_container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The path to the JQUERY library is correct...

I am opening the popup by this code:

```
var x = false;
$('#revi_print').unbind();
$('#revi_print').click(function() {

    x = window.open('report_handle/print.php?filter_report=' + $('#revi').data('filter_report'), "Popup", "width=580, height=360, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no, status=no, resizable=yes, menubar=no, location=no, directories=no, top=10, left=10");

    x.addEventListener('load', handle_popup, false);
});
```

This is the part where the actual content of the popup should get modified by using JQUERY:

```
function handle_popup() {

    x.document.$('body').append('TEST');

}
```

While it is possible to use native JavaScript like getElementById and the like on the popup, it is not possible to use JQUERY...

I get the following error message in firebug:

```
x.document.$ is not a function

x.document.$('body').append('TEST');
```

Comment: What do you think x is?

Comment: Why are you setting an eventListener to a window.open :).

Comment: x is the popup - I am setting the listener to make sure the popup is fully loaded, when I try to modify it... As the loading happens asynchronous, the popup wont be loaded when I try to modify it...

Answer (score 0):

I have just found out myself...

```
function handle_popup() {

     x.$('body').append('TEST');

}
```

I am not supposed to use x.**document** before I access it with JQUERY...